# questions related to some inequalities about various norms

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Ref.1 (Jiahong Wu, The 2D Incompressible Boussinesq Equations, Peking University Summer School Lecture Notes (2012))

When I read the proof of the global regularity for the 2D viscous Boussinesq equations in Ref.1, I found 3 inequalities that I do not understand:

$$\|\theta\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)}^2 \|\nabla\omega\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)}^2\leq \tfrac{1}{2\nu}\|\theta\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)}^2+\tfrac{\nu}{2}\|\nabla\omega\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)}^2\tag{1}$$

$$C\|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)}^2 \|\nabla^2 u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)}\leq \tfrac{\nu}{2}\|\nabla^2u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)}^2+\tfrac{C}{\nu}\|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)}^2\|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)}^2\tag{2}$$

$$C\|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)}^{3/2} \|\nabla^2 u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)}^{3/2}\leq \tfrac{\nu}{2}\|\nabla^2u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)}^2+\tfrac{C}{\nu}\|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)}^4\|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)}^2\tag{3}$$

If we use simplified symbols $a=\|\theta\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)},b=\|\nabla\omega\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)},c=\|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)},d=\|\nabla^2 u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)},f=\|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)},g=\|\nabla^2 u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)}$, then they become

$$a^2 b^2\leq \tfrac{1}{2\nu}a^2+\tfrac{\nu}{2}b^2\tag{4}$$

$$C c^2 d\leq \tfrac{\nu}{2}d^2+\tfrac{C}{\nu}c^2c^2\tag{5}$$

$$Cf^{3/2} g^{3/2}\leq \tfrac{\nu}{2}g^2+\tfrac{C}{\nu}f^4f^2\tag{6}$$

Eq.(5) is probably related to:
$$\tfrac{\nu}{2^{\color{red}{2}}}d^2+\tfrac{C^{\color{red}{2}}}{\nu}c^2c^2\geq 2\tfrac{\sqrt{\nu}}{2}\tfrac{C}{\sqrt{\nu}}c^2d=Cc^2d\tag{5B}$$

What are the known inequalities used in Eq.(1)-(3)?

Best regards!

***Added on 2023-0608***
After check several previous steps in the derivation, we found out the typo in LHS of Eq.(1). The Eq.(1) and (4) should be:
$$\|\theta\nabla\omega\|_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^2)}\leq\|\theta\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)}^{\color{red}{1}} \|\nabla\omega\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)}^{\color{red}{1}}\leq\tfrac{1}{2\nu}\|\theta\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)}^2+\tfrac{\nu}{2}\|\nabla\omega\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)}^2\tag{1B}$$
$$a^{\color{red}{1}} b^{\color{red}{1}}\leq \tfrac{1}{2\nu}a^2+\tfrac{\nu}{2}b^2\tag{4B}$$

Young's inequality with $\epsilon$ is used in Eq.(1B,4B) and Eq.(2), Eq.(5), thanks to @Nick for pointing out.

Comment: The first one is Young’s Inequality. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality_for_products See the tab “Elementary Case”

Comment: @Nick: Thanks for quick reply. But I was not able to get it.  Young's inequality is $ab \leq \tfrac{1}{p}a^p + \tfrac{1}{q}b^q\quad\tfrac1p+\tfrac1q=1,p>1$. Comparing this with Eq.(4), what values for p and q that I should pick?

Comment: You're looking at the standard version, look at the second tab on the elementary case.

Comment: @Nick: I can not access wikipedia dot org.  If it is convenient for you, please post the result for me.  Best regards-

Comment: @Nick：I got the formula for so-called Young's inequality with $\epsilon$, $ab\leq\tfrac{1}{2\epsilon}a^2+\tfrac{\epsilon}{2}b^2$.  This one is similar to Eq.(5) above, but not Eq.(4).   Eq.(4) is $a^{\color{red}{2}}b^{\color{red}{2}}\leq\tfrac{1}{2\epsilon}a^2+\tfrac{\epsilon}{2}b^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Young's inquality (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality_for_products) proof from Wiki,

Looks like only last inequality is left: But here is a general template.

$\min_{v} M(v) = \min_v v \frac{g^2}{2} + \frac{C}{v} f^6$

$M'(v) = 0 \implies \frac{g^2}{2} = \frac{C}{v^2} f^6 \implies v = \sqrt{2C} \frac{f^3}{g} $

$\min_{v} M(v) = \sqrt{2C} \frac{f^3 g}{2} + \sqrt{2C} \frac{f^3 g}{2} = \sqrt{2C} f^3 g$

So we get:

$$\sqrt{2C} f^3 g \leq v\frac{g^2}{2} + \frac{C}{v} f^6.$$

Check if there is a typo in your last inequality also and it is exactly equal to above inequality ? Ping me in the comments below.

Comment: Yes. I think that there is a typo in Eq.(3) or Eq.(6) of the original formulas in Ref.1, which is literally reproduced here.  As we found out before that Eq.(1) and (4) also contain a typo. Best